# Splash screen which fills the whole samrtphone screen, but not crop

Tags: java, android, android-layout, splash-screen

I want to have a splash screen, something like a full picture, which doesn't crop in heigth or width on different smartphone screens.

Now I achieved a splash screen with `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, but now the image is cropped on top or bottom or if the devices screen size changes to another aspect ratio it is cropped on the left and right.

What do I have to do? I've already read the android developer article `Supporting Multiple Screens`, but I don't get it how to achieve this.

A simple picture in the middle of the screen is just simple to get, but a picture which fills the screen is hard to get. Can you help me pls?

Comment: `fitXY` doesn't *crop* you image - it stretches it to fill both width- and height-wise. That being said, with the huge variety of different screen densities, aspect ratios and resolutions out there, it's going to be a tough nut to come up with an image that always fits perfectly. The only scenario is which that is going to feasible  is when you can define stretchable areas (read: create a 9-patch).

Comment: Set the image on Parent Layout as background and set the height/width attributes as match_parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `center_crop` per this purpose. From the doc

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
>   both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
>   larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create one single asset and expect it to do not be cropper and to do not create black areas when the application is deployed in different screen sizes.

The android platform is designed to work dynamically with multiple screen sizes that any manufacture can change at any time, including new resolutions that you haven't thought about it yet.

Android can specify minimums for screen hight/width categories in which your resources will fall, but those are generics.

In order to use them, you will have to specify qualifiers in your drawables and create a different splash screen for every qualifier, as for example if you use drawable-w420dp, all the resources there will be used when the screen has a minimum width of 420dp (notice that are not pixels)

So you have two options:

1. You can use one single splash image and design margins of that image flexible enough in order to cope with the image being cropped in certain cases. You can play with different scaleTypes in your ImageView and take as a reference this website http://etcodehome.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html even though as commented before, "center-crop" will be your best shot.
2. You can programatically use a specific image for a specific resolution.
   2.1 Put in the assets directory, all the splash images that you want for all the specific resolutions or aspect ratios that you want to use
   2.1 Get the screen size of the device with [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)
   2.2 Now you can load from the assets the image that you want dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

which will fill the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Width and Height of image to "match_parent"